.Renviron path issue
I'm pretty new to coding--so I apologize if this question doesn't make sense! Happy to add more context.
I'm trying to create an Renviron file to create a path to a shared data folder for collaborators to be able to load the same data in my R script. I have successfully created an .Renviron file, but when I try to save a data frame it claims that the .csv file I'm trying to load does not exist. My code is saved in a separate folder (proposal) within a parent folder from my data, which is saved in the data folder. The Renviron file is saved in the parent folder.
Does anyone have any ideas for what to do next to try to fix this so that any collaborators can load the data? Thanks in advance for your help!
Here is my Renviron file code:
vector_box_path = '/Users/firstlast/Library/CloudStorage/Box-Box/data_viz_final_hv/data/'
Here is the code where I'm trying to load my file:
box_path = Sys.getenv("vector_box_path")

vectors_group <- read_csv(paste(box_path, "filename.csv", sep = "/"))

This is where I get the following error message:
Error: '/filename.csv' does not exist.
I've already tried adjusting the /'s in my Renviron file (so both data/ and data without the / but adding the / to my filename.csv path. So, "/filename.csv" instead of "filename.csv".

You didn't say where you were storing that file.  It should be in your home directory, and it should be named .Renviron as in your title, not Renviron as in the body of your quesiton.

I'm assuming Sys.getenv("vector_box_path") doesn't return anything? That means that variable is not getting set. The variables are only loaded once when R first runs. Have you restarted R after changing your environment file? Are you sure you named the file correctly and put it in the right folder?

Hi both! Thanks for your help!
@MrFlick - box_path wasn't returning anything. However, I moved the .Renviron file into my home directory and it appears like it's running now. Thank you!
